# Jenkins pipeline usage for xcode

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Are there instructions for using the xcode plugin from a jenkins pipeline?

I'm moving some freestyle projects to pipeline and have realised I've left a step out: Import developer profile. I'd like to know how to do that from a jenkins pipeline. I assume this should involve the xcode plugin, but it does not come up in the snippet editor and I see no documentation.

Comment: Seems that https://github.com/jenkinsci/xcode-plugin/pull/74 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42457 has supposed to have added pipeline support for the Jenkins plugin, but I see no documentation nor examples.

Answer (score 1):

I got a steer to this on the Jenkins site.

IF on the snippet generator, you look under steps, there is something that generates xcode-related fragments. Don't know why this does not come out under xcode, like other plugins, but I guess that is a different matter.

I have not yet worked out how to do my original scenario but I guess I need to sit down some time and give it a good try. In the meantime, I'm using secret text for the password I need.

Comment: Still not got much further on this but probably because we are calling xcode via xmake rather than directly, and the pipeline build step is totally about setting up stuff for xcode.

I suspect the best solution is to keep the profile using secret text/file and then making explicit calls to download etc. Yet to do completely.